# Android classes absent from debug

Tags: java, android, debugging

Application works fine. I can access everything in debug except for an Array Adapter class.

Used to debug OK.

Removed app from my device, checked logs, etc.,... I can't seem to find a clue of a warning anywhere. I assume there is an error of some kind.

Any ideas on how you track that down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors can exclude classes from Debug.